# dispatch_group_notify never called

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch

I have the code outlined below, but the final call to `dispatch_group_notify` never occurs

```
    // Get friends:
    dispatch_group_enter(self.dbGetQueue)
        getFriends.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            for detailData in snapshot.children {
                
                print(detailData)
                
                self.friends.append(Member(userID: detailData.key, userName: detailData.value!["userName"] as! String))
                
            }
        dispatch_group_leave(self.dbGetQueue)
        })

    
    // Get group memebers:
    dispatch_group_enter(self.dbGetQueue)
        getGroupMembers.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            for groupMemberDetail in snapshot.children {
                
                print(groupMemberDetail)
                if groupMemberDetail.key != FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userID {
                    
                    self.groupMembers.append(groupMemberDetail.key)
                    
                }
            }
        })
    
    // Get group invites presently out:
    dispatch_group_enter(self.dbGetQueue)
        getFriendMemberInvites.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            for groupInvitePresentlySentDetail in snapshot.children {
                
                self.groupInvitesSent.append(groupInvitePresentlySentDetail.key)
            }
        dispatch_group_leave(self.dbGetQueue)
        })
    
    dispatch_group_notify(self.dbGetQueue, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // Final load of who is left of conacts (not user or friend)
        
        // Have list of friends, now set to iterate through:
        // 0: not invited yet, 1: invited (eiter declined or not replied yet) not , 2: Already a member -- will have alert noting user became a group member
        print(self.groupMembers.count)
        print(self.friends.count)
        print(self.groupInvitesSent.count)
        
        
        for aFriend in self.friends {
            
            print("Friends name is: " + aFriend.userName)
            
            var inviteStatus = Invite(userName: aFriend.userName, status: "not invited yet", statusSort: 0, name: aFriend.userName, userID: aFriend.userID)
            
            if self.groupMembers.contains(aFriend.userID) {
                
                inviteStatus.statusSort = 2
                inviteStatus.status = "member"
                
                self.memberStatuses.append(inviteStatus)
                
            } else if self.groupInvitesSent.contains(aFriend.userID){
                
                inviteStatus.statusSort = 1
                inviteStatus.status = "invited"
                
                self.memberStatuses.append(inviteStatus)
                
            } else {
                
                self.memberStatuses.append(inviteStatus)
                
            }
        }
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

How can this be alleviated?

Comment: You don't have a `dispatch_group_leave` at the end of the closure after `// Get group members:`

Comment: @Paulw11, that was it, thank you.